# Deleting Multiple Objects by ObjectId

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

`destroyAll` requires the object itself it seems..

I have tried something like this :

```
  var arrayToDelete = [];

  for (objectId in objectIdArray) {
    var rawProduct = Parse.Object.extend("Product");
    var productToDelete = new rawProduct();
    productToDelete.id = objectId;
    arrayToDelete.push(productToDelete);
  }

  Parse.Object.destroyAll(arrayToDelete, {
    success: function() {
      response.success("succeeded")
    }, 
    error: function(error) {
      response.error("failed")
    }
  });
```

But it returns failed, with a logged error of `object not found for delete`

I have manually inspected the `objectId`s: they all exist and they're the expected ones.

I want to avoid fetching the objects, as I already have a reference to them and would like to delete them in one go.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

As an initial debugging step - try calling destroyAll on each object to see which of them is causing the issue *and* log the actual error.

```
 for (objectId in objectIdArray) {
    var rawProduct = Parse.Object.extend("Product");
    var productToDelete = new rawProduct();
    productToDelete.id = objectId;
      Parse.Object.destroyAll([productToDelete], {
    success: function() {
      response.success("succeeded");
    }, 
    error: function(error) {
      console.log('destroyAll cb: ', error);
      response.error("failed: " + error);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: I already logged the code, I just trimmed it out to avoid posting too much in the question. They all fail.

Comment: From a quick google - it looks like their API doesn't want you constructing raw objects and setting the id.  It looks like they want the references to the actual objects.  From their example:

var query = new Parse.Query("Comment");
  query.equalTo("post", request.object.id);

  query.find().then(function(comments) {
Parse.Object.destroyAll(comments);

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with the code as posted.  It could be made more concise with [`Parse.Object.createWithoutData()`](https://parse.com/docs/js/api/classes/Parse.Object.html#methods_createWithoutData), but it should work as you have it.  The error indicates that at least one of the ids is wrong, that it is not the objectId of any Product object.